# Supplying Camera Attitude to OpenCV Stitcher

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, panoramas, image-stitching

I'm trying to use OpenCV to stitch together 360° panoramas from images captured on my iPhone.

The stitching algorithm is working great, but doesn't provide any empty space for the areas that I have not captured. I can receive attitude (pitch, yaw, roll) information from the phone and believe this would be enough extra information to determine how much empty space should included in the panorama that I create, but I can't find a way to provide this information to the Stitcher.

I'd like to know:

- Does OpenCV allow me to provide camera information to the stitcher?
- Will OpenCV create a 360° panorama, taking into account the empty space?
- If not, can you suggest a post-processing step that could add the correct amount of empty space to the compiled panorama?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am also looking for a solution to this...

Comment: No, it appears that OpenCV does not allow that much control. I didn't have enough time to break open OpenCV and modify it so we went with a different approach.

Comment: Oh okay, but what different approach did you take? Could you please share that with me?

Comment: For this project we decided to target Android devices that support PhotoSphere, decided that a proof of concept would be easier to build without so much effort put into stitching.